# reading a reference to an object and reading the object’s fields under JMM

Tags: java, java-memory-model

This post was raised after reading: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#pitfall-semi-sync

```
class Box {
  int x;
  public Box(int v) {
    x = v;
  }
}

class RacyBoxy {
  Box box;

  public synchronized void set(Box v) {
    box = v;
  }

  public Box get() {
    return box;
  }
}
```

and test:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
public class SynchronizedPublish {
  RacyBoxy boxie = new RacyBoxy();

  @Actor
  void actor() {
    boxie.set(new Box(42)); // set is synchronized
  }

  @Actor
  void observer(IntResult1 r) {
    Box t = boxie.get(); // get is not synchronized
    if (t != null) {
      r.r1 = t.x;
    } else {
      r.r1 = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

The author says that it is possible that `r.r1 == 0`. And I agree with
that. But, I am confused with an explanation:

> The actual failure comes from the fact that reading a reference to an object and reading the object’s fields are distinct under the memory model.

I agree that

> reading a reference to an object and reading the object’s fields are distinct under the memory model 
>   but, I don't see how it has an influence on result.

Please help me understand it.

P.S. If someone is confused about `@Actor`. It just means: run in a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it adresses a common miconception of people that read code with regards to sequential consitency. The fact that the reference to an instance is available in one thread, does not imply that its constructor is set. In other words: reading an instance is a different operation than reading an instance's field. Many people assume that once they can observe an instance, it requires the constructor to be run but due to the missing read synchronization, this is not true for the above example.

Comment: So, do you mean that?
The first thread (actor) published the reference, but object was not intialized yes. Then, an observer read reference to box (`boxie.get()`) and becasue reference wasn't `null`, the observer read `t.x == 0`.

Comment: Yes, publishing the instance and calling its constructor are not always atomic unless you make an object safe for publication.

Answer (score 1):

Ill just slightly augment the accepted answer here - without *some* barriers there are absolutely no guarantees that *once* you see a reference (think some threads can get a hold of a reference) - all the fields from that constructor are initialized. I actually answered sort of this already some time ago to one of your questions if I'm not mistaken.

There are two barriers inserted after the constructor that has final fields `LoadLoad` and `LoadStore`; it you think about their *names* - you will notice that no operation *after* the constructor can be re-ordered with one *inside* it:

```
Load -> Load (no Load can be re-ordered with a previous Load)
Load -> Store (no Store can be re-ordered with a previous Load)
```

Also note that it would be impossible for you to break that under the current `x86` memory model - as it is a (too?) strong memory model; and as such these barriers are *free* on `x86` - they are not inserted at all, because the operations are not re-ordered.